Why does Jaynes' multi-dimensional $A_p$ distribution take this form?
In Chapter 18 of Jaynes' Probability Theory: the Logic of Science, he introduced $A_p$ distribution as the "internal structure" of probability assignment $P(A|E)$, such that $P(A|E)$ is just first moment of density of $A_p$.  I kind of understand why $A_p$ is introduced this way for 1D distribution.  But in Section 18.10, he introduced K-dimensional $A_p$ density as:

which I do not quite get why it takes this form of delta function.  Can anyone explain why it takes such a form?

You may want to read David Blower's comment (Volume 2, Ch. 38.2):
The title of Jaynes’s Chapter 18 is, “The Ap distribution and rule of succession.” I have wished to go on record for quite some time now with my view as to what is going on in this part of Jaynes’s book. I have a strong feeling that this particular Chapter of his book lends itself to grave misunderstandings. I would like to do my best to clarify the confusion to whatever extent I am able. This section represents the first step in the full annotation of Chapter 18.
Basically, Jaynes presents this section as “an application” of the uniform distribution over model space to verify Laplace’s Rule of Succession for the simple case where some statement can be either true or false. Jaynes generalizes the Rule of Succession later on in Section 18.10. Unfortunately, his rationale for the mysterious Ap distribution is so obscure that it destroys his otherwise fine presentation of the essential mathematical ingredients involved in the Rule of Succession.
[...]
Pre–eminent among many confusing issues is what Jaynes mysteriously calls an “Ap distribution.” Now, I would be willing to bet that not one in a thousand understands what he means by this “Ap distribution.” To cut the long-winded explanation very short, everything becomes remarkably clear if one just substitutes P(Mk) whenever Jaynes writes or mentions this “Ap distribution.”
You can download all of David Blower's books from www.BayesInAction.nl.

thanks, can you share the link for volume 2 ?

Just go to https://www.bayesinaction.nl/books-david-j-blower/ and browse.
